# Source code file paths in Jenkins Violations plugin not working (when using StyleCop)

Tags: c#, jenkins, stylecop

I'm facing an issue with the Jenkins Violations plug-in when trying to access my source code files from the UI. The paths are relative to the root of the volume :S. So, if my .cs file is in `C:\CMSRootFolder\MySolution\MyProject\Namespace\SourceCode.cs`, then the link in Jenkins is: `http://<jenkins_server>/job/<job_name>/violations/file/CMSRootFolder/MySolution/Namespace/SourceCode.cs/`

This happens even after setting the faux project path to "C:\CMSRootFolder\MySolution", and no matter what I try to set in the source code patterns. I think this might be a bug in the plug-in, but I would like to know if there is any workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "faux project path" is must as far as I understand.

You have wrong slashes for violation plugin:
C:\CMSRootFolder\MySolution\MyProject\Namespace\SourceCode.cs
It's wait's for
C:/CMSRootFolder/MySolution/MyProject/Namespace/SourceCode.cs

Run folowing utility after violation reporter finished to work.

```
import fileinput, sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in fileinput.FileInput("path to violations.xml",inplace=1):
        if ".cs"  in line:
            line = line.replace("\\", "/")
        print line,
```